# What are the assumptions & consequence of violations of assumptions of Apriori algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, pattern-recognition, unsupervised-learning, apriori

1. What are the consequence of violations of each of these assumptions?

Comment: Each of what assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the key point of Apriori in patterns discovery is Any subset of a frequent itemset must be frequent given the minimum support and confidence. And this leads to Apriori pruning principle: If there is any itemset which is infrequent, its superset should not even be generated.

And the weakness of this algorithm is the efficiency in scanning database when do pruning. So I really do not understand of the assumptions you mentioned ? please give some details. Hopefully the above can help you.

Comment: This is **not an assumption**, but a mathematical fact. It is impossible to have a subset not be at least as frequent as the superset.